# Dynamically set the widths (weights) of Views inside a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout that contains four differently-colored Views. Each colored view represents the proportion of a workout's cumulative time spent in various heart-rate zones (blue -> green -> orange -> red).

I can get the desired effect by changing the android:layout_weight=".35" attribute in the various views in the XML. Setting these values does exactly what I want (when I don't override them in code). I think I'm just not accessing these properties correctly in code.

I have tried hard-coding nice, round sets of numbers and they don't look correct. The first one in the list appears much larger than it ought to be.

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ex_history_item"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CurrentStyle.HabitCard"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    >
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardio_bar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/cardio_none"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardio_zone_none"
            />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/cardio_fatburn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardio_zone_fatburn"
            />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/cardio_cardio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardio_zone_cardio"
            />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/cardio_peak"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardio_zone_peak"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/accent"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardio"
        android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ex_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardio_bar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bodypartLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:text="Bodypart"
            tools:text="Bodypart" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ex_image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/accent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exercise_name"
        >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exercise_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exercise Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/accent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardio_bar" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardio_table"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ex_image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="Duration"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/duration" android:text="0"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="Distance"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/distance" android:text="0"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/weights_table"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ex_image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >
    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My code for changing them is the following

```
        private final LinearLayout cardioBar;
        private final View cardioZoneNone;
        private final View cardioZoneFatburn;
        private final View cardioZoneCardio;
        private final View cardioZonePeak;





         Float total = (float)exercise.exercise.getHrTotalDuration();
         holder.cardioBar.setWeightSum(total);
         holder.cardioZoneNone.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float)exercise.exercise.getHrNone()));
         holder.cardioZoneFatburn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float)exercise.exercise.getHrFatburn()));
         holder.cardioZoneCardio.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float)exercise.exercise.getHrCardio()));
         holder.cardioZonePeak.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float)exercise.exercise.getHrPeak()));
```

I have even tried hard-coding some values in place of the ones in my objects. Strangely, it seems that setting them to 0.25 (with a weightsum of 1.0) looks correct, but most others set the cardioZoneNone much, much larger than it ought to be.

When I log the values, the numbers look appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I had read that the width should only be set to zero when using weight attribute in XML, but not when setting weight from code. Perhaps this was true when that was written, but setting width to zero *does* seem to fix my issue